# Why do two different base64 strings result in the same binary output?

Tags: encoding, base64

Can anyone explain why the base64 string `XCrgcAAAAAC82M==` decodes to the same binary data as does `XCrgcAAAAAC82A==` ?

XCrgcAAAAAC82M== xxd output

`00000000: 5c2a e070 0000 0000 bcd8                 \*.p......`

XCrgcAAAAAC82A== xxd output

`00000000: 5c2a e070 0000 0000 bcd8                 \*.p......`

Comment: [Decoding Base 64 with padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you elaborate? I don't understand how this is helpful in this scenario.

Comment: `A` = `000000` and `M`  = `001100`. But since there are two trailing `=` signs, only the first 2 bits are used, and therefore any character `A` - `P` would also decode the same.